# include a javascript file in a different folder in my index.html

Tags: javascript, html, src

my index.html and my app .js are located in different folders

```
- WEB-INF
  --resources
    -js
      -app.js
  --views
    -index.html
```

I tried to import my app.js into my index.html using :

```
<script src="../resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

but it didn't work . I got this error :

> GET http://localhost:8080/projectname/resources/js/app.js

Comment: can you give the full path, which works for app.js?

Comment: is that file/folder readable by apache?

Comment: You should consider the start point as reference, not your view's `index.html` path. Edit your question and provide the full structure if you want more help on this

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use some IDE like VisualStudio, etc.

Files on your site's root folder are referred like this:
`src="/[fileInYourRootFolder]"`

So files on a subfolder  are referred like this:`src="/[subfolder]/[fileInSubfolder]"`